# PHP comparison operators and statements of the form if (!foo())

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean, variable-assignment, comparison-operators

Here is my little script, and from writing it I've learned that I've no idea how PHP handles variables...

```
<?php 
$var = 1;

echo "Variable is set to $var <br />";

if (!foo()) echo "Goodbye";

function foo()
{
    echo "Function should echo value again: ";

    if ($var == 1)
    {
        echo "\$var = 1 <br />";
        return true;
    }

    if ($var == 2)
    {
        echo "\$var = 0 <br />";
        return false;
    }
}     
?>
```

So, here is how *I thought* this script would be interpreted:

- The statement `if (!foo)` would run `foo()`. If the function returned `false`, it would also echo "Goodbye" at the end.
- The function `foo()` would check whether `$var == 1` or `2` (without being strict about datatype). If 1 it would echo "Function should echo value again: 1", and if 2, it would echo the same but with the number 2.

For some reason **both** if statements inside `foo()` are being passed over (I know this because if I change the first if statement to `if ($var != 1)`, it passes as true, *even if I declared* `$var = 1`.

What's happening here? I thought I had all this down, now I feel like I just went backwards :/

Comment: mostly i see scope issues: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: A lot of people are going to suggest `global`, as does that link I just pasted, but please, save yourself months of going down the wrong road, and avoid `global` like the plague.

Comment: global has its place, but yes not here, and its often used incorrectly.

Comment: @Dagon I've yet to see it ever used correctly in PHP :p.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function doesn't know what `$var` is. You'd have to pass it in, or make it global:

```
function foo() {
  global $var;
  /* ... */
}
```

Or

```
$var = 1;
if ( !foo( $var ) ) echo "Goodbye";

function foo ( $variable ) {
  /* Evaluate $variable */
}
```

By the way, it's almost always better to avoid global variables. I would encourage you to go the latter route and pass the value into the function body instead.

Comment: Oh my. I'd read about variable scopes and still it completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to read [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) manual page. `$var` is invisible for `foo()` function, so it is undefined inside of it.